# difference between extract and date_part

Tags: sql, netezza, nzsql

What is the exact difference between date_part() and extract functions in netezza?

Answer (score 1):

In Netezza *date_part* and *extract* are equivalent functions. They provide different syntax for improved SQL compatibility, but are otherwise the same.

You can see this in the [documentation here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_date_time_funcs.html).

Answer (score 0):

difference between `date_part('week', ...)` and `extract(week from ...)` not only but also from a performance point of view. I read `extract` is standard and `date_part` is not. Backwards compatibility maybe justifies the existence of `date_part`